# Django template tag left / right

Tags: django

Given text. Is there a django template tag to do:

```
text = 'hello there'
text[:3] ==> 'hel'
text[-3:] ==> 'ere'
```

Something like:

```
{{ text|left:3 }}
```

If not I can build a template tag for it but was wondering if it's already provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a standard django template, you can use the slice template tag:

```
{{ text|slice:":3" }}
```

will only display the first three characters and

```
{{ text|slice:"-3:" }}
```

will only display the last three characters.

Essentially this template tag works just like the standard python slice syntax and just like standard slicing, it will work on both lists and strings. The docs only describe its use on lists so I can see why you'd be confused about this. Hope this helps!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice